# How to debug a react-native application in vs code?(as a default debugger)

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, react-native-debugger

I am able to debug my react-native application in vs code. But I should do a few additional things every time when I want to debug.

1. First I should start `npm start`
2. The app starts the default debugging in chrome. Now I should close the browser tab.
3. Start debugger in visual studio code and restart debug mode in the expo.

Instead of this, is it possible to start debugger in vs code directly instead of the above procedure?

Comment: how do you start the app? by command or directly from vs code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use chrome debugger and flipper

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).